# FTP: get and delete a specific number of files

Tags: batch-file, cmd, ftp, move

I'm trying to create a combination of batch files, with ftp commands to get and delete a specific number of files from a FTP directory.
Now I'm stuck and I get all the files but ofter, when there are more than 250 files in the directory, the batch stops and it's not possible to continue.

This is my actual situation, I have these 3 files:

**FILE 01_FTP_GetFileList.bat**

> cd C:\folder
>
> ftp -s:02_FTP_GetFileList.txt
>
> C:\folder\03_FTP_MoveFiles.bat

**FILE 02_FTP_GetFileList.txt**

> open xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
>
> user
>
> password
>
> hash
>
> prompt off
>
> cd folder
>
> lcd folder
>
> ls *.gz filelist.txt
>
> bye

**FILE 03_FTP_MoveFiles.bat**

> @echo off
>
> setlocal enableextensions
>
> setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
>
> echo open xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx>>myscript
>
> echo user user password>>myscript
>
> echo prompt n>>myscript
>
> echo ascii>>myscript
>
> echo cd folder>>myscript
>
> echo lcd C:\folder>>myscript
>
> for /F "usebackq tokens=1,2* delims=," %%G IN ("C:\folder\filelist.txt") DO echo mget %%G>>myscript
>
> for /F "usebackq tokens=1,2* delims=," %%G IN ("C:\folder\filelist.txt") DO echo mdelete %%G>>myscript
>
> echo bye>>myscript
>
> ftp -n -s:myscript
>
> del filelist.txt
>
> del myscript

To resume, the first file recall the 2nd and the 3rd and, as you can see in the code, I get and delete all the *.gz files in a specific directory after listing the files in that directory (this to avoid to delete file added after the copy).

Now I would like to copy only the first file of the list or... to list only 100 files in the folder, is the same by my point of view.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: You could put a counter into the loop and stop after 100? See `SET /A`

Comment: Yes I can, I have to put it in the third file?
In this way the filelist.txt will have the whole list but will copy just the first 100 . Right?

Comment: You might want to use `ftp -i` to turn off interactive prompting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not see any counter variable in the post. The code below uses FILE_COUNT as the counter. It is incremented by the `SET /A FILE_COUNTER+=1` statement. The FILE_COUNT is tested for being less than 100. See `SET /?`.

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

SET MAX_FILES=100
SET /S FILE_COUNT=0

FOR /F "usebackq tokens=1,2 delims=," %%a IN (`TYPE "C:\folder\filelist.txt"`) DO (
    IF !FILE_COUNT! LSS %MAX_FILES% (
        echo mget %%a>>myscript
        echo mdelete %%a>>myscript
    )

    SET /A FILE_COUNT+=1
)
```

Comment: Thank you Liturgist I just changed a thing because your wrote:
echo mget %%G and i substitute it with echo mget %%a.

Now it's working properly. It's really slow the trasfer. But works. If you have any advice for speed up the trasfer please tell me =)

Cheers

Comment: @MarcaSolkanar - My apologies. I have corrected that and a few other details in the code. I am glad it helped even if it was less than perfect.